# jersey 2.4 return JSONObject, not support List,Map to convert to json

Tags: java, json, jersey

jersey 2.4 return JSONObject, not support List,Map ,only can return POJO to json

```
@GET
@Path("/test_map")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public RestResponse testMap(){
    RestResponse restResponse = new RestResponse();
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add("test");
    data.add("map");
    restResponse.setData(data);
    restResponse.setStatus(RestResponse.EStatus.OK);
    return restResponse;
}
```

reponse:

> `{
>   status: "OK"
>   data: "test map"
>   }`

it seems jersey call the list.toString(), i want to return a list of data

> {
>   status: "OK"
>   data: ["test", "map"]
>   }

**Can do this in jersey 2.4?**

Comment: yep, this is the default behavior of `Jersey` for collections, it uses `toString` on collection-elements... search for work around `jersey` suggests for handling this.

Comment: Which of the JSON providers (MOXy, Jackson, Jettison) are you using?

Comment: @MichalGajdos i'm using MOXy now

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that will be,

Create a new Class.

Use List data = new ArrayList<>(); as member.
Implement your add method for that class, to add to your ArrayList.

Override the toString method for that class, to return the list as you want it to be.

Use that class in your code, instead of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use JacksonJsonProvider.class for marshalling and unmarshalling that can be found in jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar

just load this class in jersey resource
For example :
import java.util.HashSet;
```

import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider;

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest/v1")
public class YourResourceLoader extends Application
{
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.ws.rs.core.Application#getClasses()
     */
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```